# Linux bash script to change a string if another string exists in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need a linux bash script to loop a folder for all files and check if there is a string in them, change another string of them. For example we check if file contanis AAAA then replace BBBB with CCCC and if didn't have AAAA we change DDDD to EEEE.

I wrote some codes but I'm not sure if they work correctly:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PATH = /path/to/files/* # files has no extension

for file in $PATH; do
    if grep -q "AAAA" $file; then
        replace "BBBB" "CCCC" -- $file
    else
        replace "DDDD" "EEEE" -- $file
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-liner doing your job :

```
for i in /path/to/files/* ; do if grep -q AAAA "$i" ; then sed -i 's/BBBB/CCCC/g' "$i" ; else sed -i 's/DDDD/EEEE/g' "$i" ; fi ; done
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I write everything instead AAAA ?! I need to write something like this:  AA=AA , Does the equal break the code ?!

Comment: Yes you can ;). grep accept regular expression as pattern by default.

Comment: `grep` and `sed` will grumble about directories and calling it a one-liner is pushing it.

Comment: "Does the equal break the code?" : No, but a / can ;)... for that replace slashes in `'s/BBBB/CCCC/g'` with some other character like `|` or `#`, which is not present in the search nor replace string. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things: `PATH` is not a good variable name, see [here](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) for information about **the** `PATH` variable, i'm not familiar with the `replace` command or how widely available it is but `sed` is probably a better choice for portability, `sed -i 's/AAAA/BBBB/g'` replaces all values of `AAAA` with `BBBB` in a file, also you should always quote your variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /path/to/file/*; do       
    if grep -q "AAAA" "$file"; then
        sed -i 's/BBBB/CCCC/g' "$file"
    else
        sed -i 's/DDDD/EEEE/g' "$file"
    fi
done
```

---

```
$ cat f1.txt 
AAAA
BBBB
DDDD

$ cat f2.txt
BBBB
DDDD

$ ./script.sh 

$ cat f1.txt
AAAA
CCCC
DDDD

$ cat f2.txt
BBBB
EEEE
```

This will have an issue with directories so an improvement using `find` to select only files and also now handles files with spaces:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /path/to/file/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name | while IFS= read -r file
do
    if grep -q "AAAA" "$file"; then
        sed -i 's/BBBB/CCCC/g' "$file"
    else
        sed -i 's/DDDD/EEEE/g' "$file"
    fi
done
```